# SEO mod_rewrite internal uri directory problems

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a mod_rewrite rule that changes `example.com/en/about/topic` to `example.com/en/view.php?p=pages/about/topic.php`

My rule is:

> RewriteRule ^en/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ en/view.php?p=pages/$1.php

view.php has all my persistent stuff like menus, logo etc and it uses a php include to get pages/topic.php

It works on `example.com/en/topic -> example.com/en/view.php?p=pages/topic.php` but when I try `example.com/en/about/topic -> example.com/en/view.php?p=pages/about/topic.php`, it finds `view.php` and `pages/about/topic.php` and loads them but tries to load all my css files and images etc. from `en/about/...` instead of `en/...` It does this for images in both view.php and topic.php. The most frustrating thing is that if I add [R] to the rule, everything works fine but it defeats the purpose of the SEO exercise!

I’ve been at this all day but no luck. Though I did discover mod_rewrite logging and a couple of [handy](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#gen3) [guides](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/).

Here’s what my log says for example.com/en/test (which works):

> [perdir C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/] rewrite 'en/test' ->
>   'en/view.php?p=pages/test.php'
>
> [perdir C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/] strip document_root prefix:
>   C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/en/view.php -> /en/view.php
>
> [perdir C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/] internal redirect with /en/view.php
>   [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
>
> [perdir C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/] pass through
>   C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/en/view.php
>
> [perdir C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/] pass through
>   C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/en/base/code/view.css

and for example.com/en/about/test (which does not)

> [perdir C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/] rewrite 'en/about/dir/test' ->
>   'en/view.php?p=pages/about/dir/test.php'
>
> [perdir C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/] strip document_root prefix:
>   C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/en/view.php -> /en/view.php
>
> [perdir C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/] internal redirect with /en/view.php
>   [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
>
> [perdir C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/] pass through
>   C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/en/view.php
>
> [perdir C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/] pass through C:/tt/xampp/htdocs/en/about

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Oh, just thought - I know I could change my image urls etc to absolute but I'd really rather not (a lot of files!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a way you are asking the wrong question.  The rule that you give works and does what you want.  Your problem is that the scripts are issuing relative addresses for your CSS, images, etc. so when the client browser requests `example.com/en/about/topic` which contains a relative link `href="base/code/view.css"`, the *client* will convert this to

```
example.com/en/about/base/code/view.css
```

Given that you don't want to change your scripts, your challenge is therefore to recognise this type of pattern and strip out the extraneous directories that the SEO encoding introduces, so if this case is `example.com/en/<don't care>/base/code/...` then the following type of rule will do what to want

```
RewriteRule en/.+?/base/code/(.*) en/base/code/$1   [L]
```

Replace `/base/code` by whatever match patterns you need.

Comment: Brilliant! Thankyou! That makes perfect sense. I hadn’t realised that the client still bases its requests on the entered address, not the modified ones. That also explains why all of the php still worked as it is server side.